# List rendering waiting until all components are created - I want them to appear one by one

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have some components on a planner that take a little time to load the data they need. What *used* to happen is they would each load in turn, I would see each day appear on the planner as it loaded. Now though, I see a white screen untill **all** the components have loaded.  I think this may have been since an upgrade in my vue version (I can't be sure as I've moved over to a different UI framework so lots of changes have been made)

This is the component render (I've dumbed down my example as much as poss):

```
<div
  v-for="(date, index) in plannerDates"
>
  <planner-day
    :date="date.date"
    class="day-container col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-xl-2-mod"
    :key="index"
  />
</div>
```

`plannerDates` starts of as `[]` but is loaded based on 2 date filters. In short, it's something like `loop - this.plannerDates.push(someMoment)`

Within the created event on the `planner-day` component, I call a couple of methods that relatively take a little while to process:

```
created () {
  this.loadDay(this.date)
  this.dataLoaded = true
  console.log('Day loaded: %s', this.date.format('DD/MM/YYYY'))
},
```

I see the console logs appearing with about a quarter of a second gap between each so I am also expecting my components to show on the page with a quarter of a second gap as well but all I see is them appearing as one.

Note: If I add a console log into the `mounted ()` I see all the created first **then** the mounted so I expect this is the issue but how can I get Vue to mount each component in turn?

Comment: I think you should use a key. I think a key would help vue easily understand the data that is loaded and the data that is new. Though I'm not sure if that will fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry, my normal code has a key but I accidentally removed it when minimizing my example.

Comment: Have you tried using `nextTick()`?  https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what is happening is that all the DOM changes are getting queued up then happen all at once (since you are adding stuff to the array over a short period of time).  Using `nextTick()` will basically wait for that DOM update queue to be flushed before proceeding.  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst making an unrelated change to my app, I wrapped my `loadDay()` method in a promise and this has in turn caused the components to render one after another again. It would appear that the methods need to be able to run asynchronously in order to render one after another in the way I was expecting (it makes sense now I think about it).

With that in mind, setting the created method this resolved the issue:

```
created () {
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    this.loadDay(this.date)
    this.dataLoaded = true
    console.log('Day loaded: %s', this.date.format('DD/MM/YYYY'))
  })
},
```